# Node.js Api calls in an Async loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach, callback

I'm having difficulty making multiple api calls and getting the returned results in the right place.  This what I'm trying to achieve: Two loops, nested.   The outer loop loops over a complex json object and places some object's values in an array call box.  The inner loop calls the api and the places the returned results in an array named bag. So I have box and bag full of data.  When both loops and api calls end, I would like to have access to the data in both box and bag and do stuff with it. I'm just not sure of the best way to go have access to both arrays at the same point in execution. This is what I have so far, but of course bag and box are empty because they get called before all the loops and api calls end.

```
var data = {}//a json object with data;
var bag = [];
var box = [];

async.forEach(data.item, function(item, callback){

    async.forEach(item.name, function(name, callback){

        callApi(item.name, function(obj){

           bag.push(obj);
        });

        callback();

    }

   box.push(item);
   callback();

});


function callApi(name, callback){

    asyncApiCall(url+name, function(err, result){

        callback(result);       
    });

}

//when all loops and api requests are done
//do stuff with contents of box and bag here;
console.log(bag, box);
```

Comment: Is `async` a reference to Caolan's Async library?

Comment: If it is Caolan' Async indeed, it's not the way to use it. The Github page of Async has good examples

Comment: @BrandonTilley yes its Caolan's Async

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a counter to ensure all async calls have returned and then call a callback. An example:

```
function performAsyncOperation(data, onCompletion) {
    var bag = [];
    var box = [];
    var count  = 0;

    async.forEach(data.item, function(item, callback){
        async.forEach(item.name, function(name, callback){
            count += 1;
            callApi(item.name, function(obj){
               bag.push(obj);
               count -= 1;
               if (count == 0) {
                   onCompletion(null, { bag:bag, box:box });
               }
            });
            callback();
        }
       box.push(item);
       callback();
    });
}
```

`count` and `onCompletion` are the important parts above.

Comment: I could see how this would work immediately. And it did work. However, I don't like having flags all over the place. The overall positive aspect of this solution for me is to get used to thinking in callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have the full dataset, you should first (synchronously) gather the list of names into one single array.

Then, only do one level of `async.forEach`.  Trying to do this with two level is unnecessary and results in more complex code.

If what you refer to as `async` is what you get using `npm install async`, here's a piece of code that illustrates what you could use (uses `lodash` to build the list of names, as this tends to be more consise.

```
var _ = require("lodash");
var async = require("async");

var data = {
  item: [
    {name: "a"},
    {name: "b"}
  ]
};

var bag = [];

var items = _(_(data.item).collect(function(item) {
  return item.name;
})).value();

async.eachSeries(items, function(name, cb) {
  callApi(name, function(obj) {
    bag.push(obj);
    cb();
  });
}, function done() {
  console.log("bag", bag);
});

function callApi(name, cb) {
  cb(name);
}
```

And the output is:

```
bag [ 'a', 'b' ]
```

Comment: +1 for lodash because I've been using underscore. Also I think this is a good approach, but I still needed nested loops because of complexity of my data object.